# how to compile and then create lib file QtpropertBrowser

Tags: qt, cmake, qt5, qt-creator, qproperty

how to compile and then create lib file QtpropertBrowser. I want to add this library on my project. this library  https://github.com/airpaio/QtPropertyBrowser . How can ı do.

can you help me?

Comment: Have you read the [`INSTALL.TXT`](https://github.com/airpaio/QtPropertyBrowser/blob/master/INSTALL.TXT) file?

Comment: yes ı read, but ı do not create .lib file